# How to remove text input when switching buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not quite having the test inputs right for the "Yes", "No", "True" and "False" buttons. You can see and test for yourself [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php). Please follow steps below:

1. Click on "Open Grid" and select button "True or False", "True" and "False" buttons will appear.
2. Click on button "True", the button will turn green and you will see the text input for that button below. This is fine.
3. Now click on the "False" button, what happens is that the "False" button is turned on and the "True" button is turned off (goes back to being white). Now the good thing is the "False" text input appears, the bad thing is that it does not remove the "True" text input.

So what my question is that if the user clicks on alternative buttons of either "True" or "False" or "Yes" or "No", I want the button which has just been turned off to have it's input removed.

How can this be achieved?

Below is the function which adds and remove the inputs:

```
      function btnclick(btn)
{
    var context = $(btn).parents('#optionAndAnswer');
    if (context.length == 0) {
        context = $(btn).parents('tr');
    }
    var $btn = $(btn);
    var value = btn.value;
    var id = $btn.attr('id');

    var $otherYNBtn = value === "Yes" ? $(context.find("input[value='No']")) : $(context.find("input[value='Yes']"));
    var $otherTFBtn = value === "True" ? $(context.find("input[value='False']")) : $(context.find("input[value='True']"));


    if ($(context.find("input[value='Yes']")).hasClass('answerBtnsOn')) {
        $otherYNBtn.removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }

    else if ($(context.find("input[value='No']")).hasClass('answerBtnsOn')) {
        $otherYNBtn.removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }

    if ($(context.find("input[value='True']")).hasClass('answerBtnsOn')) {
        $otherTFBtn.removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }

    else if ($(context.find("input[value='False']")).hasClass('answerBtnsOn')) {
        $otherTFBtn.removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }


    if ($(btn).hasClass('answerBtnsOff')) {
        var n = $("input[name='" + id + "value']").length;
        var hid = "hidden" + id + n + "value";  
        $(btn).attr("data-hid", hid);

        // append those values to the form
        var input = '<input type="text" id="' + hid + '" value="' + value + '" name="' + id + 'value" />';
        $('#QandA').append(input);      
        // toggle the button
        $btn.removeClass('answerBtnsOff').addClass('answerBtnsOn'); 
    // do the opposite - remove the input
    }
    else {
        $("#" + $(btn).attr("data-hid")).remove();
        $btn.removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }  


    $('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : 0);

    return false;
}
```

Below are the "True", "False", "Yes" and "No" buttons:

```
 <table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
    <tr>
    <tr class="answer">
    <td>3. Answer</td>
    <td>
    <table id="answerSection">
  <tr>
<td>
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerName[True]"  id="answerTrue"    type="button"   value="True"    onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerName[False]" id="answerFalse"   type="button"   value="False"   onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerName[Yes]"   id="answerYes"     type="button"   value="Yes"     onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerName[No]"    id="answerNo"      type="button"   value="No"      onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
</td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bjqr6/12/

Overall your approach is not the best way to go about it, but I wouldn't have time to do it from scratch. Next time, I would consider putting your Questions and Answers into classes and just maintaining a global array for the values. That way generating the Html code will be a heck of a lot easier to separate from the actual values and properties that matter.

Comment: .html() takes me to another page after I click on a "True" button for example, the text input is then showed on another page. should I use something else than .html('')?

Comment: actually I tried .append('') but it still hasn't sorted problem out of removing text input when switching buttons.

Comment: It's taking you to another page? If you are using .append to add those to the #QandA area, then jQuery('#QandA').html('') will empty that div. It shouldn't take you to a new page.

Comment: Ok give us 10 mins to set up the fiddle

Comment: Ok, I have set up the jsfiddle which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bjqr6/4/). I have reduced the code which is easier for you. I only include the buttons "True" or "False". You can append rows by clicking on the "Add Question" button. Can I ask a huge favour, you don't have to do it but I want to know if you can include some kind of count in your fix code so that we know which text input belongs to which button? It is virtually what the saml is saying in his answer for this question

Comment: Updated with a fix including a counter of sorts to at least track the index of the question/answer.

Comment: Can I ask 1 quick question, I actually don't want the text input to appear if the "True"or "False" button was clicked on in the top control, I only want it to appear for the buttons in the appended rows, would that be an easy fix?

Comment: Well, you could remove the buttons. Or just remove the onclick call: http://jsfiddle.net/Bjqr6/13/ please tell me you will be checking/voting this answer lol.

Comment: I need the buttons on the top control to be able to turn on and off, I just don't want to display the text input for the buttons on the top control. And of course you will definetly get best answer and I have upvoted your answer as well :) Just if you can sort this little thing for me then you have made me happiest person in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend keeping a counter of the Question count so that each Option and Answer box has an id so that you can remove any existing boxes from it before you add the new one.  This would also allow you to update it retroactively (set the third after you've added the fourth question)

Comment: Can you show me a sample code on how to set a counter, if oyu don't mind, it will be very helpful for me :) I can see how it is then done for future use